# Arrays within Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, jagged-arrays

Lets say I have a few arrays

```
dim names(3) as String
names(0) = "Name1"
names(1) = "Name2"
names(2) = "Name3"
names(3) = "Name4"

dim descriptions(2) as String
descriptions(0) = "blah1"
descriptions(1) = "blah2"
descriptions(2) = "blah3"

dim people(1) as Array
people(0) = names
people(1) = descriptions
```

How would I access those out of people??
Like this?: 
    people(0)(0)
or this: 
    (people(0))(0)

which should be "Name1"
When I try to get names out of people I get an error...

Answer (score 2):

It would be:

```
Dim name1 As String = people(0)(0)
```

However, this structure is very confusing. You have to remember what type of thing is at each index in each array, and there's no way to reliably relate a name to a description.

It would be better to build a `Person` class with `Name` and `Description` properties, then, build a list of new `Person` objects, even if some of their properties are `Nothing` (null). Using jagged arrays isn't very maintainable and even your simple example above is hard to swallow.

Here's how I would approach this (with some comments thrown in for explanation). It's more code than your example, but it will be far more maintainable

```
Public Class Person

    ' Private backing fields
    Private _name As String
    Private _description As String

    ' Default constructor
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' Overloaded constructor that takes a name and optionally a description
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, _
                   Optional ByVal description As String = Nothing)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Description = description
    End Sub

    ' A property (getter & setter) for Name
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' A property (getter & setter) for Description
    Public Property Description As String
        Get
            Return _description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _description = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And create a new list of them:

```
Dim people As New List(Of Person)

people.Add(new Person("Name1", "Description1"))
people.Add(new Person("Name2")) ' Description is optional
people.Add(new Person("Name3", "Description2"))
```

Then you can use the various methods provided by the `List(Of T)` class to find a manipulate items in the list without ever needing to know an index.

**Edit**: If you want multiple descriptions for a person, your code might look like:

```
Public Class Person

    ' Private backing fields
    Private _name As String
    Private ReadOnly _descriptions As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    ' Default constructor
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' Overloaded constructor that takes a name and optionally a description
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, _
                   Optional ByVal descriptions As IEnumerable(Of String) = Nothing)
        Me.Name = name
        If Not descriptions Is Nothing Then
            Me.Descriptions.AddRange(descriptions)
        End If
    End Sub

    ' A property (getter & setter) for Name
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' A property (getter) for Descriptions
    Public ReadOnly Property Descriptions As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _descriptions
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

And create a new list of them:

```
Dim people As New List(Of Person)

' Because the constructor takes any `IEnumerable`, you have options
' as to how you add descriptions

people.Add(new Person("Name1", New String() { "Desc1", "Desc2" }))

' or

Dim person1 As New Person("Name1")
person1.Descriptions.Add("Desc1")
person1.Descriptions.Add("Desc2")

people.Add(person1)
```

There are several other ways to do it but these two are simple.

Comment: What if I tried using a list as one of the parameters. Let's say the description is a list of strings, not a string. 'Dim descriptions As List(Of String)'. Would all of the values added to that list get passed into the value of the property of the instance of the object if I just did: 'people.Add(new Person("name1", descriptions)'

Comment: @user2922390: I added a separate example if you want multiple descriptions for a person. You would need to change the underlying `Description` property to also be a `List(Of String)` instead of just a `String`.

Comment: I did that but if I set it to description, then change description, then access the description in the list the list will have changed with the description.